# change tabcontent not using tabwidget

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

Does anybody know if there is a way to change my selected current tab, whitin the Activity that fills Tabcontent, instead of waiting the user to press the tab on the tabwidget?

For example I want to change my current activity showed in the tabwidget when the user press a botton in that activity (thus, not in the TabActivity).

Answer (score 0):

Call [`setCurrentTab()`](http://goo.gl/2ZLR4) on your `TabHost`.

Comment: but I'm not in the TabActivity, how can  i see the TabHost from the tab_content activity?

Comment: @John Smith: "but I'm not in the TabActivity" -- then the tabs are not on the screen (in which case, setting the current tab is irrelevant), or you are using deprecated techniques for creating tabs (`setContent()` that takes an `Intent`).

Comment: I expressed myself in a wrong way: the TabActivity is showed, and there is a tab selected and showed. Inside the activity associated with that tab, I want to find a way to change the tab, TabHost is reachable also in this "sub" activity?

Comment: @JohnSmith: "Inside the activity associated with that tab" -- this is a deprecated technique. "TabHost is reachable also in this "sub" activity?" -- no. `getParent()` should return the `TabActivity`, though.